# How to run given function in Bash in parallel?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

There have been some similar questions, but my problem is not "run several programs in parallel" - which can be trivially done with `parallel` or `xargs`.

I need to parallelize Bash functions.

Let's imagine code like this:

```
for i in "${list[@]}"
do
    for j in "${other[@]}"
    do
    # some processing in here - 20-30 lines of almost pure bash
    done
done
```

Some of the processing requires calls to external programs.

I'd like to run some (4-10) tasks, each running for different `$i`. Total number of elements in $list is > 500.

I know I can put the whole `for j ... done` loop in external script, and just call this program in parallel, but is it possible to do without splitting the functionality between two separate programs?

Comment: Try using functions. Or something like `var1=\`ls && pwd && ls && pwd &\`` inside your loop.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to run *all* iterations at once. I'd like to have like 4 concurrent worker processes, and if any of them finishes - start new one. Kind of like: `cat work_params | xargs -L1 -P4 do_bit_of_work` works.

Comment: Hmmm... 4 workers. I guess you will have to set up some kind of semaphores then. And poll for them periodically.

Comment: Check out [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)

Comment: Might be easier to rewrite as a makefile (... I can't believe I just wrote that with a straight face...) and use `-j`.

Comment: @glennjackman: you do realize that I wrote about parallel, and even why it's of no use in my case?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Edit: Please consider [Ole's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17316302/1899640) instead.

Instead of a separate script, you can put your code in a separate bash function. You can then export it, and run it via xargs:

```
#!/bin/bash
dowork() { 
    sleep $((RANDOM % 10 + 1))
    echo "Processing i=$1, j=$2"
}
export -f dowork

for i in "${list[@]}"
do
    for j in "${other[@]}"
    do
        printf "%s\0%s\0" "$i" "$j"
    done
done | xargs -0 -n 2 -P 4 bash -c 'dowork "$@"' --
```

Answer (score 62):

[`sem`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/sem.html) is part of [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) and is made for this kind of situation.

```
for i in "${list[@]}"
do
    for j in "${other[@]}"
    do
        # some processing in here - 20-30 lines of almost pure bash
        sem -j 4 dolong task
    done
done
```

If you like the function better GNU Parallel can do the dual for loop in one go:

```
dowork() { 
  echo "Starting i=$1, j=$2"
  sleep 5
  echo "Done i=$1, j=$2"
}
export -f dowork

parallel dowork ::: "${list[@]}" ::: "${other[@]}"
```

Comment: @jamshid Did you remember `export -f dowork`? If yes, then you may have found a bug that appears on your system. As a work around: Try `env_parallel` instead of `parallel`.

Comment: Yes, I did "export -f dowork". This is on "Ubuntu 16.04 LTS" running bash. Earlier versions (e.g. 20150522) do not have this problem. Okay, env_parallel works around this problem.

Comment: @jamshid Should be re-fixed in newest release.

Comment: @k0pernikus `/bin/sh` tells me that you are running this from `/bin/sh` which typically does not support functions. Try using `/bin/bash` instead. If you are making a script simply replace `#!/bin/sh` with `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: For future reference: commands run inside of `dowork()` seem to inherit their STDIN from the parent process, which may create conflicts for that command. See [this answer](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie/issues/150#issuecomment-21419373) which helped me make `httpie` run in parallel functions.

Answer (score 14):

An efficient solution that can also run multi-line commands in parallel:

```
for your_loop; do
  
  # wait if all 8 workers are busy
  if test "$(jobs | wc -l)" -ge 8; then
    wait -n
  fi

  # create a worker sub-process
  {
    command1
    command2
    ...
  } &
done
wait
```

In your case:

```
for i in "${list[@]}"
do
  for j in "${other[@]}"
  do
    if test "$(jobs | wc -l)" -ge 8; then
      wait -n
    fi

    {
      your
      commands
      here
    } &
  done
done
wait
```

If there are 8 bash jobs already running, `wait` will wait for at least one job to complete. If/when there are less jobs, it starts new ones asynchronously.

Benefits of this approach:

1. It's very easy for multi-line commands. All your variables are automatically "captured" in scope, no need to pass them around as arguments
2. It's relatively fast. Compare this, for example, to parallel (I'm quoting official `man`):

> parallel is slow at starting up - around 250 ms the first time and 150 ms after that.

3. Only needs `bash` to work.

Downsides:

1. There is a possibility that there were 8 jobs when we counted them, but less when we started waiting. (It happens if a jobs finishes in those milliseconds between the two commands.) This can make us `wait` with fewer jobs than required. However, it will resume when at least one job completes, or immediately if there are 0 jobs running (`wait -n` exits immediately in this case).
2. If you already have some commands running asynchronously (`&`) within the same bash script, you'll have fewer worker processes in the loop.

Comment: For downside #2, adding a `wait` command before the loop makes sure that there are no asynchronous commands left; a `wait` command after the loop may also be wanted.

Comment: @tricasse indeed! Thanks for the remark, edited the answer to include `wait` at end. Regarding the wait before loop -- this may not be intended as, who knows, maybe the script wants to run something intentionally in parallel with the main loop. So I left that part untouched.