# Parts of a Shell Script in Parallel

Tags: shell, parallel-processing

I have a shell script that contains 4 diferents parts. Each part do not depends on one another. How can I run these 4 parts in parallel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run given function in Bash in parallel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307800/how-to-run-given-function-in-bash-in-parallel)

Comment: @docksteaderluke : While the title of the posting suggests a duplicate, if I read the answers there, I have the impression that they are not what the OP wants.

Comment: @user1934428 please explain why.

Comment: The accepted answer in this posting was to use `xargs` for parallelizing. This differs - at least in my understanding - in two aspects from the question asked here: (1) If you have a certain (small) number of **different** tasks, using `xargs` to parallelize is IMHO an unnecessarily cumbersome way to do it, when your shell already offers builtin constructs for doing this. (2) The `-P` option of xargs, which is used there for parallelizing, only *advices* `xargs` to do things in parallel. There is no guarantee, that indeed this number of parallel processes will be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could process them in the background:

```
part1 &
part2 &
part3 &
part4 &
wait
```

Comment: This is executing 4 separate scripts in parallel. The OP states that he has 1 script with 4 parts (functions).

Comment: Well, I left it open in my posting, whether the 'parts' are functions or separate scripts or `{....}` constructs, but of course the OP might need to refactor his script - without seeing it, we can't know for sure. In any case, I didn't state this fact explicitly, because I thought it is obvious. The essencial point in this question is, I think, that for parallelism we can send the individual parts into the background, and then can use the `wait` builtin to synchronize.